# Javascript PHPBB-like URL tag processing

Tags: javascript, regex, bbcode

I'm working on a PHP dynamic web page that has a `<textarea>` element that lets user write text and have it show in "real time" in a `<div>` element, just JavaScript-processing the text and tags.

I change the "b", "u", and tags between brackets (like phpBB style) to their HTML equivalents like "strong", "u", and so on using JavaScript regexps.

Problem occurs when I need to process the `url` tag, where I need to extract the URL from input that looks something like this:

```
[url=http://...]
```

How can I replace that with:

```
<a href="http://...">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
str.replace(/\[url=([^\s"<>\]]+)\]/gi, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
```

That should take the parameters in `[url=...]` and, barring any funny business (`<`, `>` or spaces), change it to a hyperlink, using the URL as both the destination and the link text.

This will allow things like `[url=javascript:while(1)alert('Boo!')]`, which will produce a link that, when clicked, will really annoy the user - you'll have to add some sanitisation filtering to block stuff like that.

Comment: Great. I've just noticed I didn't add the double-quote character ( " ) to the list of disallowed characters - I'd recommend squeezing it in so the tag link doesn't end early and screw things up. I've added it in to the regex now.